# Android inside class toast not working?

Tags: android, toast

toast not working inside class,

here is my code:

```
public class ToastClass {

public ToastClass (Context activity){   
        callToast(activity);
    }   
    public void callToast(Context activity){
            Toast.makeText(activity, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }   
}
```

error i'm getting this,

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

i need do inside class is there any way do.

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you have to make+show your `Toast`s on the main thread. It is not allowed to `Toast.makeText(...)` within any other thread.

If you only want to delay your Toast, use `Handler`, otherwise you might use any `View` instance to [`postDelay(Runnable, long)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) your Toast.

In your case, you've got an `Activity` instance, so you may call it's [`runOnUiThread(Runnable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method.

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       Toast.makeText(activity, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(
 new Runnable(){
  @Override
  public void run(){
   Toast.makeText(activity, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

`ClassName.this` instead of activity